# Handle all UITextView changes including Auto-Correct and "." Shortcut

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

When using `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)` it doesn't register text changes triggered by autocorrect when tapping somewhere (to accept the autocorrect suggestion bubble)

When using `func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool` it takes double space as two spaces and not as period+space like it's configured by default as "." Shortcut in Keyboard Settings.

Using both these methods will lead to duplicate calls.

Is there a method to get all text changes?